# PhoneGap Camera onActivityResult crashed 2.3.6

Tags: android, cordova, camera

```
Possible duplicate
```

I am implementing Camera plug-in in Android using PhoneGap framework, its work on 4.0 and other but can't run in 2.3.6 android version. When taking capture and back to activity application crashed and here is the logcat detail. I am unable to fixing it.

```
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=34, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.wtd.android.phonegapplugin/com.wtd.android.phonegapplugin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    ... 12 more
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:857)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
04-16 16:54:36.171: E/AndroidRuntime(31774):    ... 13 more
```

Now the problem with 2.3.6 version I have found in 4.0 I have tested it works very well.

I am using `cordova-2.6.0.jar` file, `cordova-2.6.0.js`

How to overcome this? How to get camera captured image?

My AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wtd.android.phonegapplugin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: check these http://stackoverflow.com/a/8241969/1329126  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10943932/1329126

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap camera failure when retrieving data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750372/phonegap-camera-failure-when-retrieving-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the version of phonegap to 2.1.0 to test with lower version and its work perfectly. No idea what the problem was getting using PhoneGap 2.6.0 while also it was work perfectly in 2.3.6 version in emulator but in my device getting Force Close always